# C# how to pass var as function parameter

Tags: c#, function, var

i have a big problem.
I didnt understand how to do something like this:

```
Void DoSomething(var variable)
//Do something
```

Do someone knows?
( I want to pass unknow type to my function and do something with it)

Comment: `DoSomething(object variable)` or `DoSomething<T>(T variable)`

Comment: @fubo i think this is what user is asking. you should put it as an answer

Comment: the question / usecase is not clear enough to me - sahar lando could you add some more code what you're trying to do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: You can't pass `var` as a function parameter.

Comment: What things are you trying to do with the parameter?